# how to fix "InvalidSeeds" error in AssociatedTokenAccountProgram?

Tags: solana

all

i created a new spl-token.
and,

1. i created a new wallet.
2. i sent 1 sol to the wallet.
3. i'm trying to create an associated token account on new wallet. (error)

I made function by referring to solnet (https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet)).

error code:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32002,"message":"Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address","data":{"accounts":null,"err":{"InstructionError":[0,"InvalidSeeds"]},"logs":["Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]","Program log: Create","Program log: Error: Associated address does not match seed derivation","Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 5140 of 200000 compute units","Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address"],"unitsConsumed":0}},"id":4}

source:

```
  Solnet.Wallet.PublicKey owner = new Solnet.Wallet.PublicKey(sourceAccountOwner.GetPublicKey);
  Solnet.Wallet.PublicKey mint = new Solnet.Wallet.PublicKey(tokenMint);

  transaction = new TransactionBuilder().SetRecentBlockHash(blockHash.Result.Value.Blockhash).
                   AddInstruction(
                     AssociatedTokenAccountProgram.CreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
                       owner, // new wallet PublicKey
                       owner, // new wallet PublicKey
                       mint)) // Mint Token Address
                    .Build(new List<Account>()
                    {
                      sourceAccountOwner // new wallet
                    });
  return await activeRpcClient.SendTransactionAsync(Convert.ToBase64String(transaction));
```

how to fix "InvalidSeeds" error??

```
CreateAssociatedTokenAccount(PublicKey payer, PublicKey owner, PublicKey mint) {
  PublicKey associatedTokenAddress = DeriveAssociatedTokenAccount(owner, mint);
   ...
}
```

```
public static PublicKey DeriveAssociatedTokenAccount(PublicKey owner, PublicKey mint) {
  bool success = PublicKey.TryFindProgramAddress(
                new List<byte[]> { owner.KeyBytes, TokenProgram.ProgramIdKey.KeyBytes, mint.KeyBytes },
                ProgramIdKey, out PublicKey derivedAssociatedTokenAddress, out _);
  return derivedAssociatedTokenAddress;
}
```

```
public static bool TryFindProgramAddress(IEnumerable<byte[]> seeds, PublicKey programId, out PublicKey address, out byte bump) {
  byte seedBump = 255;
  List<byte[]> buffer = seeds.ToList();
  var bumpArray = new byte[1];
  buffer.Add(bumpArray);
  while (seedBump != 0) {
    bumpArray[0] = seedBump;
    bool success = TryCreateProgramAddress(buffer, programId, out PublicKey derivedAddress);
    if (success) {
      address = derivedAddress;
      bump = seedBump;
      return true;
    }
    seedBump--;
  }
  address = null;
  bump = 0;
  return false;
}
```

```
public static bool TryCreateProgramAddress(ICollection<byte[]> seeds, PublicKey programId, out PublicKey publicKey) {
  MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream(PublicKeyLength * seeds.Count + ProgramDerivedAddressBytes.Length + programId.KeyBytes.Length);
  foreach (byte[] seed in seeds) {
    if (seed.Length > PublicKeyLength) {
      throw new ArgumentException("max seed length exceeded", nameof(seeds));
    }
    buffer.Write(seed, 0, seed.Length);
  }
  buffer.Write(programId.KeyBytes, 0, programId.KeyBytes.Length);
  buffer.Write(ProgramDerivedAddressBytes, 0, ProgramDerivedAddressBytes.Length);
  SHA256Managed sha256Managed = new SHA256Managed();
  byte[] encryptBytes = sha256Managed.ComputeHash(buffer.GetBuffer());
  publicKey = new PublicKey(encryptBytes);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an issue in `TryCreateProgramAddress` -- be sure that the address that you generate matches what's generated by a different library.  Specifically, I think you can remove this line:

```
buffer.Write(ProgramDerivedAddressBytes, 0, ProgramDerivedAddressBytes.Length);
```

You can also use the spl-token cli as a check.  For example, if your mint is `Dgeuy4DQEeH9JYuuwph9UBrjahHxVMbBPWzL1kAx9ZNA`, you can do:

```
$ spl-token address --verbose --token Dgeuy4DQEeH9JYuuwph9UBrjahHxVMbBPWzL1kAx9ZNA
Wallet address: 4SnSuUtJGKvk2GYpBwmEsWG53zTurVM8yXGsoiZQyMJn
Associated token address: Ea9e4Z5Adu8LL8ExEVR7jC9vke3ftFdKtBhEEyRRPpJ2
```

And make sure that you properly derive `Ea9e4Z5Adu8LL8ExEVR7jC9vke3ftFdKtBhEEyRRPpJ2`